# How to connect Kotlin to Raspberry P

Tags: python, android, kotlin, raspberry-pi

I am going to made and app in Android Studio that control an arm thru Raspberry Pi 4 (Python).

The main page with the buttons wrote in Kotlin is already made with the relative movement buttons (move up, move down, move right and move left).

I don't know how to connect Kotlin to Python via Wi-Fi or Bluetooth and then send the commands to move the robotic arm.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `MQTT communication` there are a lot of its examples, and library about it, you just need to google a bit of it.  Here's some example of it  [this](https://medium.com/swlh/android-and-mqtt-a-simple-guide-cb0cbba1931c)  and  [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/link-python-applications-with-your-android-device-using-mqtt-c8e2c80f6a61) The main idea is you need to transfer the result from your android apps (like move forward, back, left or right) to your raspi (python server) and execute the rest of it.